# || operator ignored, both commands are executed

Tags: bash, shell, operators

Been unsuccessful figuring out why the OR operator is ignored and both commands are executed.

```bash
find / -ipath /usr/bin 2>/dev/null -print -quit || echo "Not a valid directory"
```

```
/usr/bin
Not a valid directory
```

Been experimenting with command substitution and grouping but the result is the same or find is ignored.

```bash
{find / -ipath /usr/bin 2>/dev/null -print -quit || echo "Not a valid directory"}
```

```
Not a valid directory}
```

```bash
$(find / -ipath /usr/bin 2>/dev/null -print -quit) || echo "Not a valid directory"
```

```
-bash: /usr/bin: Is a directory
Not a valid directory
```

Comment: what do you think your `find` commands do? what do you want them to do?

Comment: Unless you have a command called `{find` it is not surprising that that fails. You'd have seen an error message if you hadn't redirected stderr.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: `find` is running into an error, but the `2>/dev/null` hides the error message. Since `find` exits with an error status, the `||` makes the `echo` command run. Remove the `2>/dev/null` to see what's causing the error.

Comment: What are you trying to do??? `find` doesn't return differently if it finds a file or not. Won't `[ -e /usr/bin ] || echo "Not valid"` do? (Or `-d`.) I see you're making the check case-insensitive, but `-e` should work fine on a case-insensitive system.

Comment: there's no good reason to redirect stderr here.  It only serves to hide problems.

Comment: Basically, 'find' is a part of a script that takes the variable $REPLY ( usr/bin is just used as an example ) and checks if the directory exist. If so, it makes a backup of that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we remove `2>/dev/null`:

For the first `find` command we may see something like:

```bash
$ find / -ipath /usr/bin -print -quit
find: ‘/lost+found’: Permission denied
find: ‘/root’: Permission denied
/usr/bin
$ echo $?
1
$
```

So we see that `find` continues running after errors, but returns a non-zero exit code at the end. So the "OR" would trigger and your `echo` would run.

---

For the second case:

```bash
$ {find / -ipath /usr/bin -print -quit
sh: {find: not found
$ echo $?
127
$
```

This has attempted to run a comand called literally `{find`, which does not exist. This also returns a non-zero result. So the "OR" would trigger and your `echo` would run.

Note that `{` is only special to the shell when it appears as a separate word at the start of a command; and `}` is only special after `;`, a newline, or in a few other situations. Consider:

```bash
{true || echo ok}
```

```bash
{ false || echo ok;}
```

```bash
{ false || echo ok
}
```

```bash
{ false || echo ok}
```

(Note that the fourth of these is still waiting for a terminating `}`.

---

Finally, using `$(` ... `)` causes the shell to execute the command inside the parentheses and then carry on as if its output were part of the original commandline. Consider:

```bash
$ echo hello
hello
$ $(printf 'ec%co h%c' h e)llo
hello
$
```

When you applied it to `find`, the shell attempted to use `find`'s output as the command to run. `/usr/bin` is, as the error stated, a directory and not a program.

It is more normal to use `$(`...`)` to produce arguments to a command rather than to generate the command itself.

Comment: The statement about where `{` and `}` can appear is a [gross simplification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04).

Comment: The statement about `$(...)` is also a [gross simplification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01).

Answer (score 0):

`find` succeeds when the command is valid and 0 or more results are found.
When you don't want to use `test -d /usr/bin || echo "Not a valid directory"` for some reason, you can check the length of the `find` output

```
test -n "$(find / -ipath /usr/bin)" || echo "Not a valid directory"
# or
find / -ipath /usr/bin | grep -q .  || echo "Not a valid directory"
```